# convolution on partial differentiel eq

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is the question :

Let $\Phi \in S(\mathbb{R^n})$, $f \in L^p\mathbb{(R^n)}$. Define the convolution of $\Phi*f$ and show that this $\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R^n})$. Do we have $\Phi*f\in L^p\mathbb{(R^n)}$?

I started with the computation:  $\Phi*f(x) = \int_\mathbb{R^n} \Phi(y)f(x-y)dy$. I corrected the convolution

What can I do to prove the two points?

Comment: For the first,  integrate $\Phi \partial_{\dots} f$ n-times and use the fact that that all boundary values at $\infty$ of $\Phi$ vanish. For the second: use $max \Phi$ as a constant dominating the integral.

Comment: Your convolution definition is wrong. It should be $\Phi(y)$. You can then change variables $z=x-y$ then differentiating $\Phi*f$ only differentiates $\Phi$ inside the integral.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with Φ∂…f.